# Is it correct to say "enrich skill set"

Tags: word-choice

## Problem

From the separable explanations of individual words (see [enrich](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enrich) and [skill set](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skill%20set)). It seems to be fine to write this way. However, after simple google search, there seems to be no similar usages.

I am wondering if this looks professional (since it is in resume). If not, what should I use if I would like to express "___ has improved my skills"?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just say ' . . . has improved my skills'? Why do you feel the need to use the phrase *skill set* rather than simply *skills*?

Comment: @jsw29 I share you feeling. I have asked myself same question. But somehow "... enriched skill set" looks better in the context.

Comment: You must have been thinking "enhance" instead.

Comment: It tells the reader nothing.  I don’t know what you knew before or what you know now.  Better use of space would be to tell which skills you gained.

Answer (score -2):

You would use the past-tense of "enrich" and say "enriched my skill set." You would use "enrich my skill set" as more of a future task or outcome.

Comment: @ Thank you for your reply! So you find it professional to use "enriched my skill set"?

Comment: Not as an entire sentence obviously, but I assume that is just a fragment. Rewording your example: "___ has enriched my skill set" would be professional.